# Crystal Reports 2008 conditional sub reports prompt for parmeters twice

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, subreport

I am using crystal reports 2008 in PeopleSoft with a SQL Server backend. I have a Master report with an underlying query which filters on parameters passed to Crystal Report (EMPLID and Calendar Year these are the underlying tables' Primary Keys).
The master report has sub reports all linked to the the master's EMPLID and Calendar Year fields.
At this point everything works I enter the emplid and year at the prompt and the report runs filtering on those fields.

Each year, the report will change. I set up the subreports so that when I enter 2014 in the prompt, the 2014 version of sub report A will display. If I enter 2015, the 2015 version displays.

When I add these parallel subreports, I get prompted twice. I have checked all of the sub report links. I have made sure that each link selects data in the subreport based on the master field, not the subreport parameter field. I have tried this with conditional subreports and conditional sections and get double prompts. I am stumped. Any ideas of how to use conditional subreports in this way without being prompted more than once?

If this works I intend to add sub report versions for each year. If anyone can think of a better approach feel free to let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @Thriben, welcome to SO. Even though your post is quite descriptive, you should also provide some points on which the community will be able to assist you. Code would be a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly...

Have created similar parameters in sub report as main report and linked both sub report and main report parameters using sub report links? If you have not done that then will suggest you to do that so that only once parameters are prompted.

Now.. `I don't think your approach is suggested` where you are manually adding one sub report for one year, What I would suggest is you to take only one sub report and pass the parameter to the `Record Selection formula` of the sub report so that I will pick data as per the `parameter` and your report will also be not complex.

Let me know if you have any different issue.